# How to fit div with y-overflow-scroll inside parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following problem within a `<td>` cell: a parent `<div class="editor-window">` contains a `<label>` and a child `<div>`. The child `<div>` is appended with another `<div>` when the page loads.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnnkL34b/).

```js
var propertyGrid = $("<div class='property-table' />");
var editorWindow = $("#property-editor");

editorWindow.append(propertyGrid);
```

```css
.content {
    //    hard-coded values for fiddle
    width: 225px;
    height: 200px;
}
.editor-panel {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
.editor-window {
    border: 1px solid rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.75);
}
.v-scroll-window {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.editor-header {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
    color: #00004f;
    font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.max-window {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.property-table {
    display: table;
    width: 206px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="content">
    <tr>
        <td class="editor-panel">
            <div class="editor-window max-window">
                <label class="editor-header">Property Editor</label>
                <div class="v-scroll-window max-window">
                    <div class="max-window" id="property-editor" /></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that the parent `<div>` of `#property-editor` is overflowing its parent:
[image: div overflow on y-axis]

The header `<label>` must remain fixed while the lower `<div>` has vertical scroll. Any ideas on how to fix the overflow?

Comment: Add the working code snippet here or on http://jsfiddle.net please.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov: done ... thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: One of your div doesn't have closing div tag.

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh already fixed it in my answer.

Comment: @IAbstract did you see my answer? Could you comment on it?

Comment: @SergeyDenisov: I will as soon as I get back to that issue

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution — to use `calc()` for `height` (if you have the fixed header size and don't need to [support IE9-](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)):

```
.v-scroll-window {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 14px);
}
```

**The fixed snippet** ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/zLagfsoz/4/)):

```js
var propertyGrid = $("<div class='property-table'/>");
var editorWindow = $("#property-editor");

editorWindow.append(propertyGrid);
```

```css
.content {
    width: 225px;
    height: 200px;
}

.editor-panel {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.editor-window {
    border: 1px solid rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.75);
}

.editor-header {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
    color: #00004f;
    font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0;
}

.max-window {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.v-scroll-window {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 14px);
}

.property-table {
    display: table;
    width: 217px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="content">
    <tr>
        <td class="editor-panel">
            <div class="editor-window max-window">
                <h5 class="editor-header">Property Editor</h5>
                <div class="v-scroll-window max-window">
                    <div class="max-window" id="property-editor"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

By the way:

> *The HTML Label Element* (`<label>`) represents a caption for an item in a user interface. It can be associated with a control either by placing the control element inside the `<label>` element, or by using the for attribute. Such a control is called the *labeled control* of the label element. With one input can be assosiated few labels.

You shouldn't use [label tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) in this case — you have no `<form>` or control elements. I think it's OK to use something from [Heading elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements), for example, `<h5>`.